# what is the difference between "Token filter" and "ingest node" in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, analyzer

I am new in elasticsearch and I am confused with these two terms.
**Token filter** and **ingest node**. 
 They Both Turn a token to another thing, for example, a lowercase token, or etc ... and ingest node can do it too.
Can anyone explain to me when I should use which one? Thank you a lot

Comment: An ingest node is an elasticsearch node, part of a cluster, that ingest data (all ES nodes ingest data by default). If I understand right, a token filter is used in an [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/analysis.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A token filter is used as part of the [analysis process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) for text fields. An analyzer may contain zero or more token filters. For instance, the `standard` analyzer uses the `lowercase` token filter to lowercase letters.

[Ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) enable you to apply transformations on indexed documents. You can have dedicated nodes for running ingest pipelines if you want to improve performance, but that's typically only something you will want to do if A) you index a lot of documents through ingest pipelines, and B) you have a cluster consisting of quite a few nodes.

Generally speaking, a token filter and an ingest node have nothing to do with each other. It's true, however, that you can transform data within an ingest pipeline in the same way (and more) as you can do with token filters.

Comment: thank you for your answer but for example if I want to turn all letters of a string to lowercase, which way is the right way? @ba0708

Comment: This is done by default for all of your `text` fields, since they use the `standard` analyzer. This analyzer uses the `lowercase` token filter as mentioned. If you make use of dynamic mapping (i.e. you don't specify explicit field mappings), Elasticsearch will actually map string values in two ways; a `text` mapping and a `keyword` mapping. The former is tokenized and the tokens/terms are lowercased, while the latter is a no-op analyzer (used for exact matches, aggregations, etc.). I hope that helps. :-)